# Finding Values Outside Expected Ranges of Data Sets

Tags: statistics, analytics, business-intelligence

I have a data set with the following information: `SaleDate, ItemId, QuantitySold` (in MSSQL database, but general ideas are welcome).

I want to be able to generate "alerts" when there is an abrupt increase or decrease in sales for items, e.g. `Item #54321 was expected to sell between 12,000 and 15,000  in the last month but sold 18,000 pieces`.

What would be a good way to calculate the "expected range" or the abnormal values that should trigger an alert?

Averages?  Medians?  Quartiles?  Standard Deviations?  Box and Whisker plots look interesting but is that the way to go?  are there better ways?

TIA

Comment: As with everything related to statistics, answer to your question will heavily depend on how you define "good".

Comment: maybe "good" is not the best word then. I am sure that this was done many times before and is implemented by many systems. I do not wish to reinvent the proverbial wheel, but instead go with a solution that has been tested before and "approved" by many.

Answer (score 1):

This is a difficult topic. I don't really have a good suggestion, just a lot of warnings based on working with retail data in a global home furnishing company :)

**Challenges:**
The average sold quantity per day of Sofas or Kitchens are gonna be a lot different than the nr of candles or napkins sold per day. This makes it difficult to come up with a "fixed" nr.

The average sold quantity of any product in one country may be totally different in another country.

The average sold quantity of any given product at one popular location may be totally different from the average quantity of the same product in some less popular location, even in the same region.

Adding or removing selling locations have an impact on the totals in absolute terms.

Seasonal products sell close to nothing during large parts of the year, and then everything in one go at some specific point during the year. Looking at typical "summer" or "winter" products this also various between countries and the time of the year.

Products under promotion could easily display abnormal (but expected) sales pattern.

Products may sell more or less depending on external things, such as weather, day of the week or depending on what day the population receives their work check.

**Depending on what you want to do with the alerts:**
If you are planning on removing abnormal data, make sure you have a really good way of putting it back, in case you flagged a "false positive".

Likewise, if you plan on just flagging but leaving in the abnormal data, make sure you have a reliable and fast way of removing them.

If you plan putting abnormal data in some kind of "Quarantine", expect that if you flag too many records per day, nobody is gonna have time to validate them.

I think it all boils down to why you want to identify abnormal patterns.
If it is about detecting mistakes and bad data, that's one thing. If it is about identifying potentials in recent changes in sales patterns, that's another thing.

Comment: it's about identifying recent changes in sales patterns.  thank you for your reply.  I'm not sure that it qualifies as an answer, but it definitely contains good information so I am upvoting it.